# How to add Google Pixel to Chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

Does anyone know how to add Google Pixel as a new mobile device to the Chrome developer tools?

Comment: Use "Pixel 2" from the device dropdown menu. They have identical resolution and pixel density.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of a way to add a custom device with the Android UI (like the Nexus devices have), but you can add a custom device:

1. Open Chrome Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
2. Turn on the Device Toolbar if it's not already open (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)
3. On the Device Toolbar, click the dropdown with the device name and select "Edit…"
4. Under "Emulated Devices", select the "Add Custom Device" button
5. In "Device name" type `Google Pixel`
6. In "Width" and "Height" boxes, type `412` and `662` respectively
7. Leave "Device pixel ratio" and "User agent string" blank, and make sure the dropdown is set to "Mobile"
8. Press the "Add" button

Google Pixel will now show up in the Device Toolbar as a selectable device.

#### Caveats:

- This does not add the Android UI, but should be representative of the viewport for mobile development and testing (as measured on my device with the default settings).
- This also does not take into account a user changing the "Display size" in the Google Pixel's Display settings, which could make the viewport larger or smaller.
- The viewport will be slightly shorter (fewer vertical pixels) in Chrome on Android when the page first loads since the toolbar is visible, but scrolls away. The values above were measured without the toolbar.

Comment: Its important to use the device pixel ratio to get the correct display and feel. It's 3.5 for Google pixel.

Comment: @Gautam no, it isn't. The OG Pixel has a devicePixelRatio of 2.6250.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wide variety of devices (included Pixel 2, Pixel 2 XL, Pixel 3 and Pixel 4) [dropdown list of devices in dev mode with 'edit' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBXvU.png)

And you can add custom devices (if the one you are looking for is not in the list), all you need to know is the screen resolution.
[add custom device image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmtIX.png)

Or if you want to test a screen resolution just once and don't want to save it, you can just play with the width and height 'till you find the one you want.
[play with x and y image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDuhW.png)